# Dividing specific column numbers using a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a text file, like this:

```
# MarkerIndex 
# TiltAngle (degrees)
# PositionX (px)
# PositionY (px)
# 
  0  -62.450  1526.64  1205.00
  0  -60.460  1507.84  1205.36
  8   15.890  1535.96  2281.44
  8   17.890  1538.96  2281.40
  8   19.890  1542.60  2282.08
  8   21.900  1545.96  2282.32
  8   23.900  1550.64  2282.40
  8   25.900  1554.52  2281.68
  8   28.000  1559.36  2281.88
  8   30.090  1563.56  2281.32
  8   32.190  1568.64  2280.80
  8   34.280  1573.12  2280.56
```

I want to keep the first two columns as-is, the third and forth column, divided by 4.  How can I do it?

Comment: The tool is Awk. Can you try this [simple Awk tutorial](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~dholland/computers/awk.html)? You will learn a wonderful text-processing tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this task with [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html) which is a standard bash tool for text processing, for arithmetics on files and similar.

I see that the input file changed, so let's see `printf`, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html) how to define the format of the arguments. Also `NR<=5` is for the first 5 lines, to stay untouched and be printed as headers

```
awk 'NR<=5 {print; next} {$3=$3/4; $4=$4/4}
    {printf "%3s %8.3f %8.2f %8.2f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}' file
```

Output:

```
# MarkerIndex 
# TiltAngle (degrees)
# PositionX (px)
# PositionY (px)
# 
  0  -62.450   381.66   301.25
  0  -60.460   376.96   301.34
  8   15.890   383.99   570.36
  8   17.890   384.74   570.35
  8   19.890   385.65   570.52
  8   21.900   386.49   570.58
  8   23.900   387.66   570.60
  8   25.900   388.63   570.42
  8   28.000   389.84   570.47
  8   30.090   390.89   570.33
  8   32.190   392.16   570.20
  8   34.280   393.28   570.14
```

Answer (score 0):

Below bash script will paste first two columns as it is and next 2 columns divided by 4 into output.txt file.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/path/file.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
col1=$(echo "$line" | awk {'print $1'})
col2=$(echo "$line" | awk {'print $2'})
col3=$(echo "$line" | awk {'print($3/4)'})
col4=$(echo "$line" | awk {'print($4/4)'})
echo "$col1 $col2 $col3 $col4" >> output.txt
done < "$file"
```

I hope this is what you wanted.